# Not possible to use JSF with camunda tasklist?

Tags: jsf, camunda, tasklist

I want to use the **camunda tasklist with JSF external forms**. My problem is that I can not get the userid from the logged in user. I need the user id to store my data.

I tried to get it via identityService from Camunda but here it is null. So I want to fill the identityService in my first task to provide it for further forms, but therefore I need to get it in my first form.

Has anyone ideas how to get the user id?

If possible I want to avoid writing an own tasklist.

Thanks for your help,
Nicole

Comment: Did a colleague of yours upvote this question? It is not a very good one. If the 'identityService' is a managed bean (cdi, ejb, spring) try just accessing the service. If that succeeds but the user id is null, the question is not JSF related.

Comment: I am afraid, I did not work with jsf for quite a while ... I found this thread, maybe it helps: https://forum.camunda.org/t/get-user-id-from-tasklist-in-jsf-cdi-bean/18933/3